# How to sort paragraphs according to their headings in Vim?

Tags: sorting, vim

Let's say we have the following paragraphs that are separated by a blank line from each other:

```
B Heading
Lorem ipsum 1.
Lorem ipsum 2.

A Heading
Lorem ipsum 3.
Lorem ipsum 4.
```

How to sort these paragraphs with respect to their headings and obtain the following text?

```
A Heading
Lorem ipsum 3.
Lorem ipsum 4.

B Heading
Lorem ipsum 1.
Lorem ipsum 2.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution is to concatenate your paragraphs before sorting.

Say that you do not use the `@` symbol in your text, you can use:

```
:%s/\(.\+\)\n/\1@/
```

to do that. Then you can sort your lines with

```
:sort
```

and at last proceed to the reverse operation to get your paragraphs back:

```
:%s/@/\r/g
```

Comment: This is clever!

Comment: Nice indeed. Why is the 2nd slash needed at the end of `:%s/\(.\+\)\n/\1@//` ?

Comment: @TransferOrbit This looks like a typo. Let's fix it, 8 years after answering :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've written the [AdvancedSorters plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4958) to simplify the three steps given by @Qeole's answer into a single command:

```
:SortRangesByHeader /\u Heading/
```

Comment: Looks great! I've long been searching for an easy way to sort folded paragraphs. I've got to try your plugin and test the `:SortUnfolded` command!